# Could a PH3 or anything abstract a proton from a positive PH3?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I had this question for an SN2 reaction including 1-bromopropane treated with PH3, I answered that the product would be a propane alkane with a PH2 group. I was wondering whether this would happen.

Answer (score 3):

There is not very much literature about this - not surprising considering how dangerous phosphine is to handle. It appears that RPH2 can be generated from phosphine + alkyl halide under basic conditions but R2PH and R3P are also formed dependent on the conditions [paper here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/znb-1990-0215/html). Without the base you will get the phosphonium halide.  This article has more details [JACS review](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.2c07688)